# "neo4j: command not found" on mac

Tags: neo4j

I was following the guideline of manual of neo4j 3.0.1, it seems to work from GUI. Yet when I was trying to start from terminal with

```
$ neo4j console
-bash: ./neo4j: No such file or directory
```

What am I supposed to do?

```
$ uname -a
Darwin MACBOXC02HMGH0DV33 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I dont believe that some stuff like `service neo4j start`or the path thing could change where I am 'cause I cannot even locate the binary, if there is any.

Comment: Do you have it installed - from the archive (.tar) or from the installer (.dmg)?

Comment: Yes definitely. I've made it clear that the server functions well from GUI by clicking the start buttom

Answer (score 0):

I think `brew install neo4j` should work. I could not make it via official .dmg though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [post](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/osx/), once you extract the tar file and moved the extracted folder (in my case neo4j-community-3.4.10) to your desired location, we call it `<NEO4J_HOME>`, (in my case it is: /Users/*userName*/neo4j-community-3.4.10), launch terminal and navigate to :

```
$ cd <NEO4J_HOME>
$ cd bin
$ ./neo4j console
```

this will run neo4j console on your localhost:7474 and you can start using it from your browser.